# Map inside Map with ui:repeat throws UpdateModelException

Tags: jsf, el, uirepeat

There is a

```
Map<String,Map<Double,Double>> priceMatrix
```

I want to use it in a

```
<ui:repeat value="#{calcModel.priceMatrix.keySet().toArray()}" var="x">
    <div style="display: inline-block; margin-right: 10px">
        <h:inputText value="#{x}" />
    </div>
    <ui:repeat value="#{calcModel.priceMatrix.get(x).keySet().toArray()}" var="y">
        <div style="display: inline-block; margin-right: 10px">
            <h:inputText value="#{y}" />
        </div>
        <div style="display: inline-block;">
            <h:inputText value="#{calcModel.priceMatrix.get(x).get(y)}" />
        </div>
        <br />
    </ui:repeat>

</ui:repeat>
```

if i post the formular, i get a UpdateModelException with the Message:

```
value="#{calcModel.priceMatrix.get(x).get(y)}": Illegal Syntax for Set Operation
```

This issue is making me terrible since over 6 hours. My first idea was to provide own getter and setter in my bean. This dosn't work because jsf calls the getter before calling the setter.

Is there a solution for my problem?

Would it be better to work with List?

Thank you!

Comment: My fault, JSF does not require Setters on Maps. And it is able to handle Maps too.. For a simple Map it is like:
`<h:inputText value="#{calcModel.priceMatrix[x]}" />`
But with a Map in a Map?

Comment: If i remove the inner map theres no problem with the post.

Comment: Sorry, I have no idea, did not tried something like this yet. But I am very interested in a possible solution for this use case :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
<h:inputText value="#{calcModel.priceMatrix.get(x).get(y)}" />
```

This is indeed not a writable value expression. This represents a read-only value expression. EL can't figure out how to invoke setters on it as the EL expression represents a chain of method calls not nested properties.

You need to replace it by a writable value expression with help of brace notation `[]` which represents nested properties.

```
<h:inputText value="#{calcModel.priceMatrix[x][y]}" />
```

Your other inputs also don't look good, `value="#{x}"` is surely also not writable, but you'll by now able to figure out the right syntax: just use `#{map[key]}` syntax instead of `#{key}`.

Note that this is not specifically a JSF problem. The root cause your exception as you can find further down in stack trace is a `javax.el.PropertyNotWritableException`. As its package `javax.el` says, it's an EL problem, not a JSF one.

Comment: That work better but there are still errors. The post works now. But value Changes on <h:inputText value="#{x}" />  are not working. Old values stay after reload.        And changes on <h:inputText value="#{y}" />  push a new entry in the map.  Thats crazy. Any solution?  Thank you.

Comment: @Moinsn, preferably you open new questions for new problems so you don't overburden one person, and others can benefit from the answers.